# How to keep my html website design alive with images css js on Herokuapp

Tags: javascript, html, css, heroku

I have created a simple one-page responsive design demo website that I want to test across all major devices. I want to change my website design on my local machine and then deploy it to Heroku so I can test my website on a public website across multiple devices.

I have deployed my simple one-page responsive design demo website on Heroku but it is not displaying in proper (design)format. I want my website keep alive with images css and js on heroku.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: check the network inspector - sounds like an include (js/css) isn't loading correctly.

Comment: hi john i have done it but how to edit my static website after deployment on herokuapp